# order of data types from greatest to least precision in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, boolean, precision, abstract-data-type

according to my professor, its boolean, unsigned integer, integer, float, complex, string, and object.

but why? how is a float less precise than an integer (for example)? Is it to do with the operations that ca be performed on a given item (ie the ore specific the things that can be performed, the most 'precise' the type is?) I really have nothing more to add since i have really no idea, so any hints appreciated!

Comment: I didn't know `object` had a precision.

Comment: Python doesn't have "unsigned integers" or "integers". Just arbitrary precision `int`s. "complex" is just two `float`s, and a Python `float` is actually a C "double".

Comment: @MosesKoledoye maybe thats why its at the end of the list? i.e. not precise because it doesnt have precision?

Comment: This would be a good question for your professor....

Comment: Since he's including non-numeric types, I don't think he's talking about numeric precision, but some other kind of precision.

Comment: I can't imagine any definition of "precision" for which this would make sense. In particular, strings and integers in Python both have unlimited length, so in some sense have the same information-carrying capacity. I'm afraid your professor is talking nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of that he meant, that you should not do calculations with long commma floats, as they will overflow and give you some kind of rounding. If you calculate with integers instead, you wont get them. and you cold shift commas later on. 
as Artyr already mentioned, there is no unsigned Integer in Python, thats more a C/C++ World.

I don't realy know what an Objects precision should be.